# How do I get an onClickEvent on a PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a settings fragment by extending PreferenceFragment. I need to know when the user clicks inside a fragment view (the whole view) which is working for regular fragments by setting an onClick event on the parent container. However, this is not working when I use a PreferenceFragment. I have the following setup in my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="clickedView">      <---- Observe this click event on the parent view

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is the PreferenceFragment:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);           
        //Can I do something here to handle the click event??
    }

}
```

So, if I add a regular fragment the onClick event is being called when I tap the screen but it is not called when I replace it with a PreferenceFragment. I am guessing the PreferenceFragment handles its own click event and do not "puch it up" to other views. Is it possible to get an onClickEvent on a PreferenceFragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the following function to intercept touch events before they reached the PreferenceFragment:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        //Do what needs to be done
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

If someone has a better solution, feel free to share it

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `SettingsFragment` to implement `OnClickListener` and handle the click event in the `Fragment` itself by `overriding` the `OnCreateView()` and `OnClick()` methods.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.settings_fragment){
            Log.d("TAG", "Settings fragment clicked");
            //Do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I am using `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` to create the PreferenceFragment. Even if I set an onClickListener on the view that is returned with `getView()` it is not being called

Comment: Is this working for you? because I have now tried to copy your code into a complete new project but I still don't get into the onClick event. Same thing happens if I try to use an `OnTouchListener` instead.